# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, but i cant find

Tags: jquery

I got this problem
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I am trying to solve, searching the missing ), but i cant finding. Someone can help me?

```
    var dropdownToggle = $( '<button />', {
        'class': 'dropdown-toggle',
        'aria-expanded': false
    } ).append( $( '<span />',
        'class': 'screen-reader-text',
        text: screenReaderText.expand
     ) );
```

Comment: You're missing brackets around the append element options

Comment: @SterlingArcher In case he still doesn't see it, post the correct code as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar I voted to close this question because syntax error, unfortunately. If somebody wants to answer it, go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing braces around the options to the `$()` call to create `<span>`.

```
var dropdownToggle = $( '<button />', {
    'class': 'dropdown-toggle',
    'aria-expanded': false
} ).append( $( '<span />', {
    'class': 'screen-reader-text',
    text: screenReaderText.expand
} ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use following code.

```
var dropdownToggle = $('<button />', {
                       'class': 'dropdown-toggle',
                       'aria-expanded': false
                      }).append('<span class="screen-reader-text">' + screenReaderText.expand + '</span>'));
```

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a useful way. _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong, and is also not useful for future readers.

Comment: This answer is missing the `<span>` with `class="screen-reader-test"`.